# org-mode export to html: links open in new tabs?

Tags: org-mode

In html created from org-mode, you can have links open in new tabs if specified as

```
#+ATTR_HTML: target="_blank" 
[[http://cnn.com][CNN]]
```

which I found [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-02/msg00550.html).

However, this doesn't work if `[[http://cnn.com][CNN]]` is a bulleted item. For instance,

```
#+ATTR_HTML: target="_blank" 
- [[http://cnn.com][CNN]]
```

Or

```
- #+ATTR_HTML: target="_blank" 
  [[http://cnn.com][CNN]]
```

1) How can I make this work, and 2) can I set this html attribute for all links on a particular page by specifying some form of this option at the top (possibly some argument to `#+OPTIONS:`)?

Answer (score 3):

I found adding the following works:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <base target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: replace string in function `org-export-attach-captions-and-attributes`:

```
diff -u -L /home/eab/.emacs.d/el-get/org-mode/lisp/org-exp.el -L \#\<buffer\ el-get/org-exp.el\> /home/eab/.emacs.d/el-get/org-mode/lisp/org-exp.el /tmp/buffer-content-8644Ge2
--- /home/eab/.emacs.d/el-get/org-mode/lisp/org-exp.el
+++ #<buffer el-get/org-exp.el>
@@ -1935,7 +1935,7 @@
            "\\|"
            "^[ \t]*\\(|[^-]\\)"
            "\\|"
-           "^[ \t]*\\[\\[.*\\]\\][ \t]*$"))
+           "^.*\\[\\[.*\\]\\][ \t]*$"))
    cap shortn attr label end)
     (while (re-search-forward re nil t)
       (cond
```

Long comment about troubles.
Let see source code of function, which parses `#+ATTR_BACKEND` into text properties.

```
(defun org-export-attach-captions-and-attributes (target-alist)
  "Move #+CAPTION, #+ATTR_BACKEND, and #+LABEL text into text properties.
If the next thing following is a table, add the text properties to the first
table line.  If it is a link, add it to the line containing the link."
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (remove-text-properties (point-min) (point-max)
              '(org-caption nil org-attributes nil))
  (let ((case-fold-search t)
    (re (concat "^[ \t]*#\\+caption:[ \t]+\\(.*\\)"
            "\\|"
            "^[ \t]*#\\+attr_" (symbol-name org-export-current-backend) ":[ \t]+\\(.*\\)"
            "\\|"
            "^[ \t]*#\\+label:[ \t]+\\(.*\\)"
            "\\|"
            "^[ \t]*\\(|[^-]\\)"
            "\\|"
            "^[ \t]*\\[\\[.*\\]\\][ \t]*$"))
...)))
```

`org-export-current-backend` is `HTML` in this case.
It works for such text

```
#+ATTR_HTML: target="_blank" 
[[http://cnn.com][CNN]]
```

like this:

1) parse whole line `#+ATTR_HTML: target="_blank"` by regexp `"^[ \t]*#\\+attr_"...`

2) parse whole line `[[http://cnn.com][CNN]]` by regexp `"^[ \t]*\\[\\[.*\\]\\][ \t]*$"`

3) delete string `#+ATTR_HTML: target="_blank"` before export to html

4) set property `target="_blank"` for line `[[http://cnn.com][CNN]]`

And then org-mode prepares html link for export with this property.

If I replace string `"^[ \t]*\\[\\[.*\\]\\][ \t]*$"` by `"^.*\\[\\[.*\\]\\][ \t]*$"` then this patched function works for

```
#+ATTR_HTML: target="_blank" 
  - [[http://cnn.com][CNN]]
```

too. But there is a problem for list

```
  - [[http://cnn.com][CNN]] 
  - [[http://cnn.com][CNN]]
  - some text
```

If I put `ATTR_HTML` before each link

```
#+ATTR_HTML: target="_blank" 
  - [[http://cnn.com][CNN]] 
#+ATTR_HTML: target="_blank" 
  - [[http://cnn.com][CNN]]
  - some text
```

then I get such output html

```
* CNN

* CNN
* some text
```

There is a extra gap in list. So, I can't get output like this

```
* CNN
* CNN
* some text
```

only

```
* CNN

* CNN

* some text
```

This example demonstrates that org-mode isn't flexible in some cases. I can write lisp function, which sets this html attribute for all links in exported text, and add this feature to `#+OPTIONS:` or something. But I can't complicate more and more org-mode exporting system in this way, because there are some org-mode syntax limitations - it is simple.

If I have problems with org-publish like these, I think: may be I need something else for make-up except org-mode? )

Answer (score 1):

You can include html into your template if you have couple of links, like this

```
My projects
- @@html:<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Example</a>@@
```