# Is there any easy way to let Org Mode not escape some letters?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I don't want Org Mode to escape some letters, especially for plain list. For example, for the following content:

1. test for a example

I don't want Org mode to escape the plain list, and just show the original text when export it to HTML.

I think I can do this by using example, literal and code block. That means following kinds of tags in Org Mode:

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE

#+begin_src emacs-lisp

#+BEGIN_HTML
```

But it is too complex for just one letter, I want something like \ to not escape the plain list. That's the style like this:

> \1. test for example

Anything lik \ in Org Mode? Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Water Lin

Comment: Try this `: 1. test for example`

Comment: This is the same as #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE, and will add some html tags when output it into html. Is there any simple way to let Org Mode just don't escape 1. charater, and don't influent the output?

Answer (score 0):

For this concrete example there is unexpected solution:

```
(setq org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator 41)
```

It disables plain lists of the form `1.`, see

```
(customize-variable 'org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator)
```

With it org code

```
  Text text text
   1. some test
  text text
```

will be exported as

```
<p>
  Text text text
   1. some test
  text text 
</p></div>
```

This solution doesn't work if in an one line `1.` should be interpreted as plain list and in next one - as plain text.
And in general there are some cases, which aren't solvable by any settings. See also my [remark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14234593/1937596) about plain lists.